# Biolinum font bold 11pt issue in tableofcontents

Tags: fonts, luatex, libertine

I found an issue in adopting the Biolinum
font, bold face at 11pt, in the 
tableofcontents. At 10pt or 12pt it works just fine, indeed. But I need to use 11pt. 
Compiled indifferently under LuaLaTeX and PdfLateX. 
Watch at the "e" character, which is not correctly aligned with the other chars. Seems 
not to scale optimally.
I think I'll send a mail to the font's author, but meanwhile I'm just asking if I 
missed something in the code...

B.t.w. please feel free to fix my English if sounds bad. Thanks.

The code which gives the issue is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, openany, twoside]{book} 
%--------------------- Fonts ------------------------------------------
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\usepackage{libertineotf}
%--------------------- tocloft (indice generale) ---------------------%
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\sffamily \bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\sffamily \bfseries}

%_____________________ BEGIN DOCUMENT _________________________________%

\begin{document}
\frontmatter 
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\chapter{abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxwyz \uppercase{abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxwyz} 1234567890}
\backmatter
\end{document}
```

**EDIT** Compiled under MikTeX 2.9, LuaTeX-0.70.2

[image: The result]

Comment: Can you please add an image showing what you're getting? As I explained you in the GuIT forum, I'm not able to see any problem with the "e".

Comment: Does the problem occur at all zoom levels and in different PDF viewers? This problem looks like something that I’ve experienced with Adobe Reader. One way or the other, Herbert’s advice to update is definitely a good idea.

Comment: I can't reproduce this on Linux with an up-to-date TL2012.

Comment: @egreg: +1. you were right Enrico. After updated that issue doesn't subsist any more. I've had a three-four months old release, that is. Now it's ok. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

update MiKTeX and then use

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, openany, twoside]{book} 
%--------------------- Fonts ------------------------------------------
\usepackage{libertine}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
%--------------------- tocloft (indice generale) ---------------------%
[...]
```